# Boolean literals in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, boolean, constants

What are the Boolean literals in PowerShell?

Answer (score 227, accepted):

`$true` and `$false`.

Those are constants, though. There are no language-level literals for Booleans.

Depending on where you need them, you can also use anything that *coerces* to a Boolean value, if the type has to be Boolean, e.g., in method calls that require Boolean (and have no conflicting overload), or conditional statements. Most non-null objects are true, for example. `null`, empty strings, empty arrays and the number `0` are false.

Comment: Thank you for this concise and accurate answer.  It really seems that Powershell is falling back on old mistakes here, though.  Why *coerce* any values... especially so loosely such that anything can be compared to a boolean?  But I am confused what the difference is between `$true`, `True`, and `true`.  Eg, `7 -eq 7` yields `True` (not `$True`).  Azure commands, such as `az group exists -n "MyResourceGroup"` yields `true` (note lower case).  What is going on?  Why so inconsistent?  All of these -- `$true`, `True`, and `true` -- are equal to `$true` when performing `True -eq $true`, etc.

Comment: @Mike: `True`/`False` is simply the string representation of a boolean. `true` should never appear in PowerShell; it's the C# literal for a boolean. In your Azure example I'd guess it's a string returned from an API. `$true` is effectively the PowerShell "literal" (technically a constant variable) for a boolean. Coercion is common for dynamic languages that allow a range of conditions to be simplified; look at JavaScript and others. It's simply a direction of language design, not merely a mistake.

Answer (score 21):

`[bool]1` and `[bool]0` also works.

Comment: To be precise, you can use lots of things that can be coerced to boolean in contexts where conversion is taking place, e.g. in a conditional statement. And in those cases you don't need to cast at all. `if ($s.Length) { ... }` is perfectly fine, for example.

Comment: For completeness, you can also produce boolean value by doing `New-Object -Type Boolean` for `false` and `! (New-Object -Type Boolean)` for `true`

Answer (score 8):

**To add more information to already existing answers**: The Boolean literals `$true` and `$false` also work as is when used as command line parameters for PowerShell scripts. For the below PowerShell script which is stored in a file named `installmyapp.ps1`:

```
param (
    [bool]$cleanuprequired
)

echo "Batch file starting execution."
```

Now if I've to invoke this PowerShell file from a PowerShell command line, this is how I can do it:

```
installmyapp.ps1 -cleanuprequired $true
```

OR

```
installmyapp.ps1 -cleanuprequired 1
```

Here `1` and  `$true` are equivalent. Also, `0` and  `$false` are equivalent.

**Note**: Never expect that string literal `true` can get automatically converted to boolean. For example, if I run the below command:

```
installmyapp.ps1 -cleanuprequired true
```

it fails to execute the script with the below error:

> Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'cleanuprequired'.
> Cannot convert value "System.String" to type "System.Boolean". Boolean
> parameters accept only Boolean values and numbers, such as $True,
> $False, 1 or 0.