# Powershell WebAdministration IF Statement with value "False" not working as expected

Tags: powershell, web-administration

I'm not sure what I'm missing. This powershell seems to be working the opposite of what I expect. Anyone know why?

```
$loadUserProfileValue = Get-ItemProperty "IIS:\AppPools\.net v4.5" -Name processModel.loadUserProfile.Value
    Write-Host "Value: $loadUserProfileValue"
    IF ($loadUserProfileValue -eq "False") {
            Write-Host "Since Load User Profile is False, we will now set it to True"}
```

Here is my Output when Load User Profile is True

```
Value: True
Since Load User Profile is False, we will now set it to True
```

Here is my output when Load User Profile is False

```
Value: False
```

The value is being picked up correctly.
The variable $loadUserProfileValue is correct.
The IF Statement is working opposite of what I'm expecting.

I can swap it to be -ne "True" and it seems to work... but why does -eq "False" NOT work?

Comment: What is the result of `$loadUserProfileValue.GetType()`? If it is a string, is it possible that there is whitespace (SPACE, TAB, etc.) at the end of the string?

Comment: Lit brings up a good point. If it is a value of `string` type, and not a `boolean`, you can use the `.Trim()` method to get rid of leading, and trailing "white" spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerShell you use the Boolean data type like this: `True = $true` and `False = $false`.

In your case you have to change False to `$false`

```
$loadUserProfileValue = Get-ItemProperty "IIS:\AppPools\.net v4.5" -Name processModel.loadUserProfile.Value
Write-Host "Value: $loadUserProfileValue"
IF ($loadUserProfileValue -eq $false) {
        Write-Host "Since Load User Profile is False, we will now set it to True"}
```

There is already a question on that topic on Stack Overflow: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581206/boolean-literals-in-powershell)

Answer (score 1):

You're testing for a string value of false when the property is likely returning a boolean value.  PowerShell's type-converter is likely what's responsible for this not throwing an error.

Change your test to use $false instead of 'false' and see if that resolves it.  Here is a great article on this:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/boolean-values-and-operators/

EDIT:  You can (and should) always check a return object's datatype and you can do this with an inherited method on all objects, .gettype().  For your code, it would be:  `$loadUserProfileValue.gettype()` and it will tell you whether the returned object is cast as a boolean, string, etc.